# Microsoft Graph API access token validation failure

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I use this URL to get id_token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=id_token%20code&
client_id=MY_CLIENT_GUID_ID_IN_HERE&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fopenid%2Freturn&nonce=alfaYYCTxBK8oypM&
state=6DnAi0%2FICAWaH14e
```

and this return result like this

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return?
code=AAA_code_in_here&
id_token=eyJ0eXAi_xxxx_yyyy_in_here&
state=6DnAi0%2FICAWaH14e&
session_state=xxxx_guid_xxxxx
```

and then i use the **id_token** to query Graph (use POST man)
[image: Graph API to query groups]

i have see this post [InvalidAuthenticationToken and CompactToken issues - Microsoft Graph using PHP Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665769/invalidauthenticationtoken-and-compacttoken-issues-microsoft-graph-using-php-c) but make no sense.

Answer (score 4):

OATH 2.0 requires multiple steps. The first request returns an OAUTH Code. The next step is converting that OATUH code into a Bearer Token. This is the step you are missing here.

I would also recommend using the [v2 Endpoint](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/converged_auth) which is a lot easier to work with (particularly with Graph). I wrote a [v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) that walks through the process and may be helpful as well.

Comment: I am using v1 endpoint, could you also see my this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872642/insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation

Comment: The same workflow (redirect->code->token) applies to v1. The reason I recommend v2 is that it is much easier to maintain and scopes are defined by the app itself rather than the registration record.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the token directly, there is one more step to exchange the **code** you get from the response url into token.

Here is my C# code (using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)

```
      public static AuthenticationResult ExchangeCodeForToken(string InTenantName, string InUserObjId, string InRedirectUri, string InApplicationAzureClientID, string InApplicationAzureClientAppKey)
      {
                Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InTenantName), "InTenantName must be provided");
                Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InUserObjId), "InUserObjId must be provided");

                if (CanCompleteSignIn) //redirect from sign-in
                {
                    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(InApplicationAzureClientID, InApplicationAzureClientAppKey);
                    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Globals.GetLoginAuthority(InTenantName), (TokenCache)new ADALTokenCache(InUserObjId)); //Login Authority is https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantName
                    return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(VerificationCode, new Uri(InRedirectUri), clientCredential, Globals.AZURE_GRAPH_API_RESOURCE_ID); //RESOURCE_ID is "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
                }

                return null; 
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue today when I was playing with graph API, the problem in my case was how I was generating the token.

I used postman for generating the token wherein the Auth URL section I was adding the resource = client_id whereas it should be the graph URL. After making that change I was able to make the call via postman.

[image: GraphApi]

In order for the above to work, please make sure your application in Azure has delegated permissions to access the Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

To receive the access token and use it for profile requests, you don't need anything from server-side, you can implement the oAuth2 just from the client side.

Use the following URL for login:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&response_type=token&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&scope=User.ReadBasic.All

After successful login, user will redirected to the page with access_token parameter. Then use the following AJAX call to fetch user info:

```js
var token = login_window.location.href.split('access_token=').pop().split('&')[0];
$.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token);},
    success: function(data) {
      alert('Hi '+data.displayName);
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Note that you may need to enable **oauth2AllowImplicitFlow:true** setting from your Azure Active Directory application manifest file.

Set "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false to "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true.

Lastly, ensure that your app has **required permissions** for **Microsoft Graph** which are **sign in users** and **View users' basic profile**

Answer (score 0):

An updated answer to get access with new applications:

1. Register your app in the [app registration portal](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908).
2. Authorization request example:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read&state=12345](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read&state=12345)

Authorization response will look like this:

https://localhost/myapp/?code=M0ab92efe-b6fd-df08-87dc-2c6500a7f84d&state=12345

3. Get a token

   POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1

   Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com

   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e

   &scope=user.read%20mail.read

   &code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...

   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F

   &grant_type=authorization_code

   &client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps
4. Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph

   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

   Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiO ... 0X2tnSQLEANnSPHY0gKcgw

   Host: graph.microsoft.com

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph/api/1.0

You can also get an access token without a user, see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service