# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to query user's groups. according to https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest i do the following steps:

1. Get Code

   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
   response_type=id_token%20code&
   client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&
   redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fopenid%2Freturn
   response_mode=query&
   nonce=F8GtCajiXYKcGBtw&
   scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FGroup.Read.All%20Group.Read.All&
   resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F&
   state=HTlUWuV5su%2BG4zBE#`

**Note: 3 scopes are provided (openid, Group.Read.All , https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.All)**

and then i login in, AAD response to my web site:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return?
code=<Recieved_Code>&
id_token=<Recieved_id_Token>&
state=xxxx&
session_state=yyy
```

2. Get access_token

```
    POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    {
          grant_type=authorization_code
          &code=Recieved_Code_from_step_1
          &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fopenid%2Freturn
          &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
          &client\_id=
          &client\_secret=
    }
```

and this returns JSON

```
{
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "scope":"User.Read",
   "resource":"https://graph.microsoft.com/",
   "access_token":<Access_token_in_here>,
   ... other fields
}
```

**Note: Only User.Read scope is returned**

I use access_token from step 2) to do query

- Query User is ok: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
- Query Group is forbidden: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
  and get error 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.'

So why I request permission for 3 scopes but only get permission for only one scope ?

Comment: Scope combinations [openid, Group.Read.All] or [openid, https://xxxx/Group.Read.All] also return only "User.Read"

Answer (score 0):

Your request is using the v1 endpoint. This endpoint does not accept scopes as part of the request. With v1 you'll need to pre-configure the scopes you require within the registration record stored in Azure Active Directory.

I would recommend switching to [v2](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/converged_auth). This would allow you declare the scopes within your code and greatly simplify the registration process.