# MSAL/ Microsoft Authorization problem with Angular: How to validate id_token?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to make an authorization through microsoft using MSAL Angular library. I configured environment in MS Azure, wrote a code...After logging in I get id_token, but I cannot validate it on graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me as a Bearer. I get "InvalidAuthenticationToken" code. I searched through all stack and I still can't figure it out, even though there are some familiar threads. I want to make sure token is valid and get an email of user from response. This is my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class MsalService {

  B2CTodoAccessTokenKey = 'b2c.access.token';

  tenantConfig = {
    tenant: 'censored.onmicrosoft.com',
    // Replace this with your client id
    clientID: 'censored',
    signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_signinsignup',
    signUpPolicy: 'B2C_1_signin',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth/microsoft',
    b2cScopes: 
['https://censored.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation'],
    resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
  };

  /*
   * B2C SignIn SignUp Policy Configuration
   */
  clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
    this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority,
    function(errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
    },
    {
      redirectUri: this.tenantConfig.redirectUri,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
    }
  );

  public login(): void {
    this.clientApplication.authority = 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common';
    this.authenticate();
  }

  public authenticate(): void {
    var _this = this;



 this.clientApplication.loginPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
.then(function(idToken: any) {

_this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(
_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
    .then(
        function(accessToken: any) {
          _this.saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken);
        }, function(error: any) {
          _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(
_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
            function(accessToken: any) {
              _this.saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken);
            }, function(error: any) {
              console.log('error: ', error);
            });
        });
    }, function(error: any) {
      console.log('error: ', error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this MSAL library but I think you need the `access_token` to make the call to the graph api not the `id_token`.  In python MSAL at least, both are returned and MSAL takes care of validation and decoding of the `id_token`. You shouldn't really need to care about the `access_token` as it's intended for the graph resource, not your app.

Comment: What are you using in your authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to be missing the response_type parameter, which is required for the [Authorization code grant flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_authorization) that you are using.

Also, you can't use the token directly but need to exchange the code you get from the response url into the token.

```
 public static AuthenticationResult ExchangeCodeForToken(string InTenantName, string InUserObjId, string InRedirectUri, string InApplicationAzureClientID, string InApplicationAzureClientAppKey)
  {
            Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InTenantName), "InTenantName must be provided");
            Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InUserObjId), "InUserObjId must be provided");

            if (CanCompleteSignIn) //redirect from sign-in
            {
                var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(InApplicationAzureClientID, InApplicationAzureClientAppKey);
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Globals.GetLoginAuthority(InTenantName), (TokenCache)new ADALTokenCache(InUserObjId)); //Login Authority is https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantName
                return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(VerificationCode, new Uri(InRedirectUri), clientCredential, Globals.AZURE_GRAPH_API_RESOURCE_ID); //RESOURCE_ID is "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
            }

            return null; 
   }
```

See [related pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860103/microsoft-graph-api-access-token-validation-failure)t.