# Graph API Device Management Configuration Compliance Policy Search

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

We have multiple clients that have a security software compliance policy in place. My goal is to look into those policies, and pull out the devices that are notcomplient. Then from there look at the machine and pull what softwares are missing. I am using graph api for this process. Here is the graph I am using:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicies('$PolicyID')/deviceStatuses
```

Here are the permissions of the appplication:
[image]

We don't need the delegated nor do we need the write as we are not writing. I have tested with both and both did not work. Here is the error message I am finding:

[image]

Here is my reseach link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-deviceconfig-devicecompliancepolicy-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

I feels like a permission for the graph. What do you all think?

Edit: The code above works inside graph explorer. However, it does not work in powershell. The same permissions are granted. Same command is being fired off. I'm not sure why it works in graph but not in pwsh.

Edit:
Below is the code I am using.

```
$TenantID = "<Code>"
$AppID = "<Code>"
$AppKey = "<Code>"
$PolicyID = "<Code>"
$redirect_url = "https://localhost"

$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID"
$tokenUrl = "$authority/oauth2/token"

$Body = @{
    client_id     = "$AppID"
    client_secret = "$AppKey"
    redirect_url  = "$redirect_url"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Body $body -Method Post 
$Access_Token = $response.access_token

#Creates the header
$Header = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $Access_Token"
}

$PolicyURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicies('$PolicyID')/deviceStatuses"
$PageInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $PolicyURL -Method Get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860103/microsoft-graph-api-access-token-validation-failure):

> OAUTH 2.0 requires multiple steps. The first request returns an OAUTH Code. The next step is converting that OAUTH code into a Bearer Token. This is the step you are missing here.

Are you sending your Bearer Token to authenticate to the endpoint?

Comment: I have updated with the code that I am using to generate the information. The Graph works in the explorer, but not with this code. And yes, I know I need to loop as there is more than a hundred devices.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed an oauth 2.0 issue.

Here is the code below:

```
$Token = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenantID)/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$Body = @{
    client_id     = "$AppID"
    client_secret = "$AppKey"
    redirect_url  = "https://localhost"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}
$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $token -Body $Body -Method Post
$Access_Token = $request.access_token

$Header = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $($Access_Token)"
}

$GraphURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicies('$PolicyID')/deviceStatuses"
$PageInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $GraphURL -Method Get
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct , this looks like permission issue.
Put your access token jwt.ms and see if the below permission are present or not.

reference doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-deviceconfig-devicecompliancepolicy-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

[image]

Comment: I went to jwt.ms and the token is valid from there. Anything I need to be looking for? I have gone down the scope of the permission and added all of these permissions and tried each level with no success. The odd part of this is the code works in graph explorer but not powrshell.

Comment: Hope you have active Intune license , ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-deviceconfig-devicecompliancepolicy-get?view=graph-rest-1.0?

Comment: Yes, we have an intune license.