# Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library and InvalidAuthenticationToken in a console application

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am coding against the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)  and working in a console application. I am trying to proof out a way to get a list of loose documents from my personal `OneDrive` account. I am running into a bit of an issue with my code throwing:

> InvalidAuthenticationToken: CompactToken parsing failed with error code -2147184118.

After doing a bit of research it looks like this error is due to sending an OAuth token as an OAuth token instead of a bear. [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665769/invalidauthenticationtoken-and-compacttoken-issues-microsoft-graph-using-php-c).

Since I am working in a console application, I have been having a difficult time trying to locate any documents or tutorials on how to properly access the `Microsoft Graph` or `OneDrive SDK`.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

#### Non-working code:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", AccessToken);

            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }));

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var drive = await graphserviceClient.Me.Drive.Root.Request().GetAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

}
```

I have also added a stack trace image:

[image]

Also, I have included a Fiddle screen shot of the network traffic:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized trace of the request and response from the GetAsync() call?

Comment: @MichaelMainer-MSFT I have added a stack trace - is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry as I wasn't clear. Can you provide a capture of the request and response going over the wire from Fiddler?

Comment: @MichaelMainer-MSFT - Ah, okay - I have added that screen shot for you. I should give an update to also what I am working on in a more concessive manner. I am trying to create a console application that works with allow me to access list loose files from a user's `OneDrive` account. The reason for the `Graph SDK` is because it has the `drive` ability since I can not find a clear way to access it via the `OneDrive SDK`.

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I have the exact same error. Apparently it's because in the header, the OAuth token is sent as 'oath' instead of 'bearer', but I have no idea how to fix that in the GraphServiceClient

Comment: Is this still an issue?